# jqPlot displaying custom tooltip with cursor

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

I'm using the Cursor plugin to display a vertical line on a jqplot chart. The tooltip for the Cursor plugin is showing the X and Y values.

I want to add a piece of meta data to the plot points.

[x,y,1337] where 1337 is the meta deta.

I want to modify the Cursor plugin tooltip to show this metadeta as well as the data it already displays.

Use case: I have multiple series that have been scaled to 0-100 across all series for trending. I need to display the unscaled value.

Update:

i've got it working by hacking up jqplot.cursor.js, is there a better way?

```
Line 468: function updateToolTip(gridpos, datapos, plot){
              // ...
              s += $.jqplot.sprintf(c.tooltipFormatString, label, sx, sy, data[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I override the `tooltipContentEditor` jqplot function, it works great.

```
highlighter: {
                    show: true,
                    showMarker:true,
                    showTooltip:true,
                    sizeAdjust: 10,
                    tooltipLocation: 'se',
                    tooltipAxes: 'xy',
                    yvalues: 1,
                    formatString:'<table class="jqplot-highlighter"><tr><td>date:</td><td>%s</td></tr><tr><td>PiecesPerHour:</td><td align="right">%s</td></tr></table>',
                    useAxesFormatters: true,
                    tooltipContentEditor: function(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot){
                        var data = plot.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex];
                        var label = plot.legend.labels[seriesIndex].indexOf('Target')
                        var format = [];
                        //A little formatting to the data before I join it to the Html string
                        if (that.model.get('groupBy')==='month')
                            format[0] = new Date(data[0] + 1000*60*60*24).format('mmmm yyyy');
                        else
                            format[0] = new Date(data[0] ).format('mmmm dd, yyyy');
                        format[1] = new Number(data[1]).toFixed(1)

                        //join the data to the Html string:
                        str = $.jqplot.sprintf.apply($.jqplot.sprintf, [str].concat(format));
                        return str;
                    }
               }
```

Basically you get the Series and Point data and join it to an Html string with sprintf and then return the string.

Comment: I'm not using highlighter though, I'm using cursor.